# passing multiple params in route angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Hello I want to pass some params with routing in angular 4

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { StartGameComponent } from './start-game/start-game.component';
import { GameComponent } from './game/game.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/first', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'startGame', component: StartGameComponent },
  {path: 'game/:width/:height',component: GameComponent
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

in component **StartGameComponent**

```
      goToGameComponent(width:string,height:string){
      this.router.navigate(['game', {width:width,height:height}]);
}
```

in component **GameComponent**

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.forEach((urlParams) => {
          this.width= urlParams['width'];
          this.height=urlParams['height'];

        });
```

in app.component.html

```
<div>
  <md-toolbar color="primary">
    <span>MineSweeper Wix</span>

  </md-toolbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  <span class="done">
    <button md-fab>
      <md-icon>check circle</md-icon>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

it's throws my an error

> Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'game;width=10;height=10'

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You are mixing the syntax for required routing parameters with optional routing parameters.

Angular provides three types of route parameters:
1) Required parameters.
2) Optional parameters.
3) Query parameters.

Required parameters are for required values, such as an Id to display a detail page. Is the width and height required in your case?

Optional parameters are for values that are not always required, such as passing entered search criteria to a list page that should use that criteria.

Query parameters are similar to optional parameters but you can retain them across routes. So if you want to route somewhere and back again, you can retain the parameters.

*ONLY* required parameters are defined in the route configuration. Optional and query parameters are *not* included in the route configuration (so the path would be just 'game')

The syntax to set the parameters is then different depending on the type:

Required parameters: `this.router.navigate(['game', width, height]);`

Optional parameters: `this.router.navigate(['game', {width:width,height:height}]);`

Query parameters: `this.router.navigate(['game', { queryParams: {width:width, height:height}}])`

For more information, check this out: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing/table-of-contents

Comment: thank you for great explanation, it helps me to solve my issue.

Comment: How to grab the params from the other side? I mean from the component that you navigate to?

Comment: @DeborahK how do we pass a string parameter which has space in it like "process 1"?

Comment: what if my second param is optional?

Comment: @AA You can separate the words with "+" or URL encode it.

Comment: @knigalye You handle the required parameter as a required parameter and the optional parameter as an optional parameter. So something like this: `this.router.navigate(['game', game.id, {height: height}]);`

Comment: i have 2 params which are required. I have done the equivalent to: this.router.navigate(['game', width, height]). i am using a resolver - that's where I need to access one of the params - am getting undefined for it though: route.parent.params['height'] || route.params['height'];. any ideas?

Comment: In latest Angular, I needed to move the square brackets for the Query parameters like this: `this.router.navigate(['game'], { queryParams: {width:width, height:height}})`

Answer (score 1):

I was in need of something like to pass the multiple query parameters constructing them dynamically. So, perform the below steps to achieve the same:

For e.g.,

```js
const arrayItem = [{ source: "external" }, { fileFiler: "File Name 1" }];
const queryParams = arrayItem.reduce((arrObj, item) => Object.assign(arrObj, item, {}));  // this will convert into single object. 

// Output: {source: "external", fileFiler: "File Name 1"}
```

And finally called the below line to pass the same into route:

```
this.router.navigate([], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, queryParams });
```

Hope this helps!