# How do I pass multiple required routes in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I've seen a couple Stack Overflow questions that seem to be asking a similar [question][1], but none of them are working so I thought I would ask more explicitly.

I'm trying to pass multiple required parameters so that my URL returns

```
myURL/cohort-features/configuration-manager?template=myTemplate
```

In my component I'm passing

```
 this.router.navigate(['/cohort-features', '/configuration-manager'], { queryParams: { template: template.key } })
```

The problem is Angular is ignoring the first set of parenthesis and is just returning

```
myURL/configuration-manager?template=myTemplate
```

It's unclear why it's ignoring the first set of parenthesis. I've also tried passing the url as one string `'/cohort-features/configuration-manager'/` and I still encounter the same problem.

What am I doing wrong? How can I return both strings?
[1]: [passing multiple params in route angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746795/passing-multiple-params-in-route-angular-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second router.navigate path should not start with "/":

this.router.navigate(['/cohort-features', 'configuration-manager'],

More info on: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-navigating-between-routes/

P.S Routing to absolute and relative paths is tricky and the sintax is a bit confusing to me also ;-)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but removing the back slash doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I assume it was an absolute route, otherwise you have to remove the "/" in the first path also and use relativeTo - https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate

Comment: Other possibility is that there is a route configured in your routing module that is causing your navigate to redirect. Check your route config also and redirection just in case. Also make sure that if you type your route directly in the browser it works. These are usual suspects for routing issues hehe

Comment: Neither seems to be the case. I appreciate you trying though.

Comment: There was an issue with my configuration. In my routing-module. I had to pass it as a string.

Comment: Nice to hear you found it :-)